# bzero in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a simple client/server chat program in c. I am not understanding why one program works and the other doesn't. The programs given for client and server which are working are below. When I replace bzero(&(server.sin_zero),8) with bzero((char*)server,sizeof(server)) in both codes, it throws an error that "transport endpoint is not connected". They have implemneted using the second method and it works at this [site](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

```
Client.c

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>

    int main()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        int s1;
        char message[500];

        server.sin_port = htons(5000);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bzero(&(server.sin_zero),8); 
        s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(s1 == -1) {
            perror("socket not created\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(connect(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) == -1) {
            perror("not able to connect\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        int n = read(s1,message,500);
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("message not recieved\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%s\n",message);
        close(s1);
        return 0;

    }
```

Here is the program for the server.

```
  Server.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>

    int main()
    {
        struct sockaddr_in server,client;
        int s1,s2,len;
        char message[500];

        server.sin_port = htons(5000);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bzero(&(server.sin_zero),8); 
        s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(s1 == -1) {
            perror("socket not created\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
            perror("socket not binded\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(listen(s1,5) == -1) {
            perror("unable to listen");
            exit(1);
        }
        len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
        printf("connected");
        if(s2 == -1) {
            perror("unable to accept connection");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(message,"you are connected");
        message[strlen(message)] = '\0';
        int n = write(s2,message,strlen(message));
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("message not sent\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(s1);
        close(s2);
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bzero(&(server.sin_zero),8)
```

only zeroes out the `sin_zero` array.

```
bzero((char*)server,sizeof(server))
```

on the other hand, zeroes out the whole `struct`, thus resetting the values you set before (like `sin_port`).

Finally, **first** zero out the `struct`, **then** initialize it (just like they did it on the [site you referred to](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm); pay attention to the details :-)).

Comment: Thanks. This really helped.